# Example of a function that's uniformly continuous on a closed interval but not on an open one

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for an example of a function that's uniformly continuous on a closed interval [a,b] but isn't on an open one (a,b).

Can such a function exist? If so, can you help me find an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a function can exist, at least not if you mean the same $a,b$ in the open and closed intervals. Logically, the statement that a function $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ follows directly from the statement that it is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$. To be specific, given $\epsilon$, we know from uniform continuity on $[a,b]$ that we have some $\delta$, such that for any $x,y \in [a,b]$, $| x-y| < \delta$ implies $|f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. Now, since any $x,y \in (a,b)$ are also in $[a,b]$, the definition for uniform continuity is satisfied on $(a,b)$, and we have immediately that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$ as well.